# Get name of type alias

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get the name of an type alias?

```
export type SomeType = { some: 'property' }
```

I want to get `SomeType` - is there a way of doing this using TypeScript?

Update - why I need this:

I want to several types like this:

```
export type SomeType = { some: 'property' }
export type AnotherType = { another: 'property' }
```

I want to create a union of these:

```
export type Types = SomeType | AnotherType
```

Then, I want to create a map type:

```
export type TypeMap = {
  type: # type/name of type, e.g. SomeType
  payload: # object consisting of the properties of the corresponding,  type, e.g. { some: string }
}
```

After this, I want to have e.g. a function like this:

```
function doSomething() => TypeMap {
  return # should only allow one of the two definitions in TypeMap
}
```

Comment: What does "get MyType" mean? What are you trying to do? Can you give an example..?

Comment: I'm looking for a possibility to call a function where I can pass `MyType` and I get back a string `"MyType"`

Comment: Natively that is not possible, since it would require a runtime type-system. You can however use https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof - Just asking since there may be a better/alternative way of doing this, why do you need this?

Comment: That's not something TS will give you... instead I'd suggest doing `type TypeDirectory = { SomeType: {some: 'property'}, AnotherType: {another: 'property'} }` and then `type Types = TypeDirectory[keyof TypeDirectory]` and `type TypeMap = {[K in keyof TypeDirectory]: { type: K, payload: TypeDirectory[K] }}[keyof TypeDirectory]`.  This is more TS-friendly, since it uses string literal types which are real types you can reference, instead of identifier names which are essentially unobservable.  I can turn this into an answer if it meets your needs... otherwise the answer to this question is "no".

Comment: [Example code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEBECWAnCBjYB7FIoF4oBvAKCigGUsBbCOSALmKgGcaImAiMFLSFUJygBfANxkoAQQB2WYAAsIKeh2YBDWQqVcefJYJHixJEqEix4LAhcjI0mHCADaAawggsAMxuJUGbLgAuuKm8D4Asmpg1qTkTgDSUEjSUG4e3ip2-o6BTERQZqrxolBgaiAANlhqACZMmX4OuAmBIiTCru5ePllNIMEmngCu0phIWCk1WFS0CskA5gAUAJT18JHRsVBowEMoKZEKAHQoGlPUK1AAPFAADEcArBLkAPzMhVwzdPCcADSl5SqtTyrHYOl4-AMwja5HIeWesPIHygnBkckUyh+vwRiLKlWqdXUmgx4L0AhAQmEOMM7UGIzGEygUy+c2k8wAQrUVmtIBtiBIdnsUvlkajiUoVH8Afjgcw2LRSZCKSJDFAAPRqqBKXgoACEEg1UAARrVpUCagUwgBaG22m0APigAD8Xa6nbSgA)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had before. Would it be possible to have something like this: `type Some<T extends Payload>= {}; type Payload = { id: string }; type SomePayload = Payload & { some: 'property' }; type TypeDirectory = { SomeType: Some<SomePayload> }` and then in `TypeMap` assign the `SomePayload` type to `payload` ?

Comment: Playground: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgHgCpQgD2BAdgEwGcoAFAQxABs4z8A+AXigG8BfAbigChRJSLqtKE2ZQAlvgBcUQsABOY3AHMoHbr2jwk5KjXzD+uoQDIWMxBGkByMHLiQ5oK6s49w0VO4AiYuRADGwHByIAaiWhCekNIRyBE6gvSqXG58URAAsmRgYVxQUADaANLiuFAA1hAgcABmUOk+foHBIAC60qJ5+d0a0kWcYAJ60g2+AUEhxa1QAPQzUING+oQAFnAArpT6AEbQEAB0SvtQAETxQ7Qn3N3JrAWV1XWjTRNt7EA

Comment: ‣ "that's what I had before".. so why do you want to change it?
‣ "`type Some<T extends Payload>={}`" doesn't make much sense structurally... since that's an [empty type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces) and [doesn't depend on its type parameter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--), both of which are red flags.  I'm not even sure what you're trying to accomplish with `Some` anyway.